# Flexslider and stretched images

Tags: css, flexslider

I'm using Flexslider and I don't want a image is stretched if the image is too small to fit the flexslider width, but it should be displayed centered, with its original width and height values and with a black background-color.

Is it possible? And what CSS changes I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

set ***itemWidth*** property. It will adjust the image size inside the slider.
And add style

```
.slides li img {  
   width: 100%;  
}
```